# Mysql error:property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql

```
function checkEmail($email){
  $sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'";
  $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname);
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "prs";
  } else {
    echo "0 results";
  }   
}
```

I have this function. When I run the script error appears: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in...on line 21(if ($result->num_rows > 0)). What is wrong?

Comment: `var_dump($result);`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: you're simply assuming the query succeeded. it's saying "non-object", so it's probably going to be a boolean FALSE, signifying the query failed.

Comment: it says "bool(false)"

Comment: use if(isset($result)){if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "prs";
  } else {
    echo "0 results";
  }}

Comment: So how to change code? I'm new in php/mysql.

Comment: If you're new to PHP, it's best to pick a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that fits your style and needs and use that as a solid foundation for building your application. Each has a database layer that does a lot of this for you without needing to get hung up on low-level details. To fix this easily, follow the examples on the `bind_param` documentation linked above. It's an extra few lines of code and it makes it a lot harder to get your queries wrong.

Comment: I changed my code: $result = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=?"); $result->bind_param("s", $email); and got error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

perhaps result of query is null
check result

```
if(isset($result) && !empty($result)){
  if ($result->num_rows > 0)
  { 
    echo "prs"; 
  }
 else
 { 
   echo "0 results"; 
  }
} 
else
 echo('0 results');
```